# Programmatically print HTML file for Chrome

Tags: c#, html, google-chrome, printing

I have an HTML file with inline styles that looks and prints perfectly fine when I open it and do printing as usual from Chrome. The question is this - how do I do a silent print from inside the Chrome, granted it has the prophecies printing output I need? I have tried using WebBrowe0ser, but that's IE - not Chrome! I also tried doing it the console command way - print /D:"my printer" myfile, but that prints the source of the file, not rendering of it.
I have tried many other options - using WebBrowser is not too bad, granted it does not handle page-break-after that well, BUT I want to know how to do silent printing of a file with Chrome rendering, from a console application for example. How would I go about getting there?
I seen and will try using CEF, but to print without dialogue I will have to tinker with the source code and compile it first...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to launch chrome with --kiosk --kiosk-printing --print "pathtomyfile"?  Another parameter to look for is --enable-print-preview. Anyone can comment? Will give that a try...

Comment: What about document.print() from javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) cross-platform framework, which is based on Chromium. In particular, the [printing options](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#webcontentsprintoptions) found on `webContents` from the `BrowserWindow` module. It looks promising to me!

Comment: I'll have to go with using chrome's kiosk mode and printing silently with document.print() option. This will save me the hassle of instantiating the browser object all over again.